# How are dashes used when referring to the work of someone?

Tags: writing-style, dashes, internet, rules

Example: [Artist] - [Song]

Is that little line supposed to be a hyphen, non-breaking hyphen, figure-/en-/em-dash, horizontal bar, minus sign or double oblique hyphen? Are there supposed to be spaces surrounding that line?

I've tried to find more information about this topic on the internet, but no source seems to address this specific type of usage. The sources I've found just answer questions about how different kinds of lines generally are used.

In the titles of music videos on YouTube, simple hyphens seem to be used for this application. Is that really correct?

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done.

Comment: A hyphen is not a dash. A non-breaking hyphen is not a dash. A double oblique hyphen is not a dash. A horizontal bar is not a dash. A minus sign is not a dash. A figure dash is used for figures and you have no figures. This is like asking, if I want to buy a labrador, do I go with a cat or a parrot. Like, just look at the names. A parrot is not a labrador. A double oblique parrot is not a labrador. A figure poodle is not a labrador.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Hey, that's great to know! Thanks for contributing to the discussion! Do you think you could answer the question though? Which kind of line is supposed to be used? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @RegDwigнt, @-EdwinAshworth , It's completely disingenuous to close this for the reason that it's "unclear what you're asking". It's obvious what they are asking.

Comment: @KevinFegan I didn't vote to close the question as unclear because it was unclear to *you*. I voted to close the question as unclear because it was unclear to *me*. And I left a comment explaining why it was unclear. You are welcome to vote to reopen. And you are welcome to explain to me why you think a parrot is a kind of labrador.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no set standard here - it's just based on whatever looks good and makes sense in the situation/typeface involved.

Sometimes forward slashes are used, it doesn't have to be hyphens or dashes.